# Xcode: how do you make it to where clicking on a button start a new page with new graphics?

Tags: xcode, button, new-operator

I know how to make a button in Xcode with Interface Builder.

I'm just curious how to make a button do something like creating a new page with new graphics.

By the way, this is for a logic game I am making in Xcode so expect a bunch of questions later on.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is create button handling events, here is a site that can help you through that process.

http://web.mac.com/elvis.dowson/Tutorial/Xcode_3.0_Tutorials/Entries/2008/3/7_Handling_button_events.html

If you already know how to do button handling and just want to know how to create a new page then that is also handled by this tutorial.

Hope this helps.